# "No matching distribution found" on all pip installations in PyCharm

Tags: python, proxy, installation, pip, pycharm

I'm on Windows 7 running PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2 and Python 3.4.3, and I have the following behavior:

- Installing new packages in PyCharm (from Settings -> Project Interpreter) failed with the error message `No matching distribution found for [package name]`, e.g. `No matching distribution found for numpy`.
- Updating packages in PyCharm (from Settings -> Project Interpreter) claimed to succeed with a `Package successfully installed` notification, but did not change the package version in the table (and did not actually do the update).
- Installing new packages on the command line with pip (e.g. `pip install numpy` failed with the same error message as PyCharm.
- Updating packages on the command line gave the output `Requirement already up-to-date` and no update.

What????

Answer (score 3):

This is pip's behavior when it can't connect to the internet properly. In my case, I had Fiddler running so pip couldn't get through Fiddler's proxy.

To anyone else getting this behavior: check your network, firewalls, proxies, and so on.