# install packages pycharm due to proxy

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using pycharm with python 3.7.
I can't install any packages, due to a proxy problem. When i try this:
pip install pandas
I get this error:pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: proxy. 
But the the proxy that appears in the error, is different from the one i got in pycharm.
The proxy doesn't require credentials. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any special characters in your proxy (# or something like that)?

Comment: Is this proxy accessed with credentials? [Edit] the question and give us a little more detail.

Comment: I don't have any special characters

Answer (score 0):

kindly refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405336/6904845

hope this helps :

From termial use :

pip install --proxy http://username:password@proxy.com:port

e.g: pip install --proxy http://manojnirale:password%40@proxy.com:8080 spacy

Username:corporate id
Password having special characters  use Unicode
Unicode for @ will be %40 .
Please find the below link for Unicode conversion
https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/