# Not able to install ibm_db package via pip install or manually. its throwing OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I am trying to install ibm_db package via pycharm terminal using pip install ibm_db and end up with OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

the second approach i followed was downloaded package manually and try to install using python setup.py install and still facing same error. Any help would be appreciated. I am using python 3.7

```
(django_env) C:\Users\E57036\PycharmProjects\django_env\Scripts\ibm_db-3.0.1>python setup.py install
Detected 64-bit Python
Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 940, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 919, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 185, in <module>
    file_stream = BytesIO(request.urlopen(url, context=context).read())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm pip install wont work behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363175/pycharm-pip-install-wont-work-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: i am following all the instructions mentioned in the URL but still i have no luck..i am working on very restrictive network sometimes that causes lot of issues..i will keep posted once i have luck